# how to enable debugging USB Moto x vesão Player 6.0.1 with ADB commands?

Tags: moto-x

hello please can help me need to enable debugging USB with adb can someone please help me?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to save the mother of my deceased photos , this one with the broken screen .

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  USB Debugging must be enabled for ADB (Android Debug Bridge) to work in the first place, that's what it is for.